# How reliable is the stability of large MyISAM table?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, myisam

I have 7GB MyISAM table, which suddenly crashed. I was able to repair it, but now I make concerns and have few questions:
- May I expect more the table crashes in the future because of the growing size? (or the size is not related to the risk of crash)
- is there a risk, that MyISAM table might desintegrate so badly, that it would be not possible to recover? I remember on old dBase, which was prone to crashes without possibility to rescue data anymore. So I hope now, that MyISAM is more stable.

The traffic is moderate, about 140 connections

Thanks for answer

Comment: Why did the server crash? Without something more specific, this question is off-topic / too broad / attracting opinion based answers imo.

Comment: If MyISAM is crashing for you, why don't you migrate to InnoDB? Is there an issue that prevents you form using InnoDB? Also, it's probably wise that you set up replication so you don't lose service availability in case of table/database crash. There's no reason to use MyISAM these days. Also, like Dan wrote - **why** did it crash? It doesn't crash just like that, and the crashes aren't usually related to size as much to what you do with the table in question.

Comment: @mjh i am considering all options and I do not know the reason yet.... I know my question is not specific, because I am not experienced in this field, thats why any answer does matter.... Like yours.... Thanks

Comment: Fair enough, no problem - I'd suggest you try to use InnoDB instead of MyISAM. I don't know how complex of an operation that will be for you, but that engine is pretty much standard nowadays.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/choosing-the-right-storage-engine/

Comment: @danfromgermany good link... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/table-size-limit.html

Depends on OS file size limitations and a max size of 256TB see above.

I have run MyISAM tables higher than 7GB, I think it was greater than 20GB.
One thing you should consider is to partition the table.  This breaks the table into smaller bits so there is less risk in table corruption and if you are querying using an index on which you partitioned the table you can gain many times faster select query performance.  Admittedly it can muck up other things in certain conditions, but normally when you have a table that size partitioning is a good thing especially if you are worried about stability.

Answer (score 0):

As already noted, MyISAM has virtually no size limit.  The largest MyISAM table I have seen was 330GB of data.

When the *server* crashes, MyISAM often corrupts the index.  The necessitates a "repair", which *usually* fixes it.  However, if it were in the middle of a multi-row `INSERT` or `UPDATE` or `DELETE`, some of the rows may have been modified, while others are not.  This can lead to a different flavor of 'corruption'.  The only cure for this is to make all writes be idempotent.

InnoDB avoids the above issues.  It has essentially one drawback -- the 7GB will become 15GB-20GB.  If you have the disk space, I highly recommend [*converting*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/) .  (Yes, MariaDB supports a large number of other Engines, while Oracle is removing everything by InnoDB, but most are for narrow niches.  Without further information about your data, I would not recommend anything other than InnoDB.)